# LaTeX vs Word vs Pages Sharpness

Tags: pdf, export

I have a question regarding the sharpness/crispness of a PDF document in Latex vs Microsoft Word vs Apple Pages export.

Is it my imagination, or are PDFs created with LaTeX sharper than with Word and Pages? I feel they look better.

I use the *exact same* OTF fonts in my documents. When I zoom in, I don't see any difference, the fonts seem to be pixel sharp. However, I have the impression that LaTeX exports are sharper in a default pageview.

**All imagination, or is there more to it?**

Comment: if it's the same fonts then (probably) it's your imagination.

Comment: Maybe is not really the font but differences in kerning, line spacing, ligatures, hyphens, margins, etc.